# In Azure, how do i set a subdomain to a separate VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have an Azure VM that hosts mycompany app at mycompany.com. I'd like to have different VMs for each subdomain created like client1.mycompany.com. What i tried to do already was to have separate websites with the host header configured, but it was in the same VM.

How do i set a host name (if possible) like subdomain.mycompany.com to a different VM other than the one hosting mycompany.com?

Answer (score 1):

You use a different DNS record for each sub-domain, each resolving to the public ip address of the respective VM.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the A (host) record entry in your company.com's DNS pointting to the right vm's IP-Adress.

```
; mycompany.com
client1.      1.1.1.1
client2.      1.1.1.2
client2.      1.1.1.3
```

Where those adresses are the IPv4 addresses of the different vm's.